# Transfer href text to textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the current code I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="">Active</a>
    <a href="">Inactive</a>
    <a href="">Banned</a>
    <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is when I click on active, the textbox will have the word active and so on. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('input[type=text]').val(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: This requires jQuery, if this is what you want, then tag the question with jQuery too

Comment: I am not bashing this answer but I would seriously discourage using the entire jQuery library just for this. If you are doing a lot of interaction with the DOM sure - which might be the case - just saying.

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript you could do this:

#### html - I would suggest adding an id to the input

`<body>
    <a href="#">Active</a>
    <a href="#">Inactive</a>
    <a href="#">Banned</a>
    <input id="foo" type="text">
</body>`

### javascript

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );
var input = document.getElementById('foo');

function setInput(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    input.value = event.target.innerHTML;
};

for( var i=links.length; i--; ) {
  links[i].addEventListener( 'click', setInput, false );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

And without JQuery just in case someone wants it :
http://jsfiddle.net/s0ds5rdy/

I recommend putting "#" in the href attribute. It'll scroll to the top of the page if you don't `preventDefault`, while browsers might reload the page if you click on a blank link.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; ++i) {
        allLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value = e.target.innerHTML;
        });
    }
});
```